# Monomorphism between 2 language structures? $ \left<\Bbb N , \leq, +, 0\right> \& \left<\Bbb N , \leq, \cdot, 1\right> $?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

So my Logic teacher gave us this exercise:

Define a monomorphism between these 2 models/language structures or prove that it is impossible to define: 
$$a) \left<\Bbb N , \leq, +, 0\right> \& \left<\Bbb N , \leq, \cdot, 1\right>$$
$$b) \left<\Bbb N ,  \cdot, 1\right> \& \left<\Bbb N , +, 0\right>$$

I believe there is none for a), but yes for b) because the order relation $\leq$ won't allow it, but no matter what I imagine, nothing works. 
 
Does anybody have any idea? Thank you beforehand :)

Comment: How about $n\mapsto 2^n$ for (a)?

Comment: For (b) I think the shortest way to dispose of it would be to ask, what can the image of $0$ possibly be?